# How to make Windows 7 cmd up/down arrows show the F7 menu

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

I much prefer the F7 menu in Windows cmd than using up/down to get to recent command history. But I hate reaching for F7. Is there way to make up/down bring up that menu?

Comment: Reaching allll-thaaat-waaayy..... hehe.. OK, what have you tried already?  Have you checked out Autohotkey or alike yet (to remap keys)?

Comment: well all I've tried is looking through the cmd options/prefs dialog, and didn't see anything. I normally don't like to use stuff like AHK but I suppose that's an option. I'm hoping to find a way using existing Windows configs.

Comment: @Rich Currently Windows does not support remapping keys through any sort of control panel. The only option you have is to somehow modify your keyboard driver or use a third-party tool.